# algolia NoClassDefFoundError jayway/jsonpath/Predicate

Tags: android, json, noclassdeffounderror, algolia

I'm getting an error recently (it came up this morning has been working fine until now) at runtime when building my project. The error is coming from a library I'm using called Algolia Instant Search, here is the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
[Lcom/jayway/jsonpath/Predicate;     
at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.
JSONUtils.getObjectFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java    
at
com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.
JSONUtils.getStringFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:    
at
com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.
Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:    
at
com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.
Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:
```

etc etc until

```
04-17 12:27:05.422 20618-20618/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline 
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find 
class "com.jayway.jsonpath.Predicate" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline-1/base.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline-        
1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline-
1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline-1/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline-
1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/data/app/com.sealstudios.iconnectonline- 
1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, 
/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]


at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

my question is basically, is there anything i can do about this? roll back gradle versions, add a file, and if so how, or do i need to just inform the author and wait for a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was an issue in dependency management that caused transitive dependencies to not be exposed from v1.7.6 to v1.7.23 included.

The [release v1.7.24](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android/releases/tag/1.7.24) fixed the error. Simply update your dependency to

```
implementation "com.algolia:instantsearch-android:1.7.24"
```

and the problem will go away.

Comment: ive just checked and i was already using 1.7.15 just cleaned synced and rebuilt my project but no joy

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: Do you use JSONPath's `Predicate` anywhere? If you rely on it, you need to add JSONPath to your dependencies (`implementation('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.3.0')`) as InstantSearch doesn't provide it anymore. If not, do you have the same issue when building https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples ?

Comment: I don't use it in my project no, the error is saying that hits (instant search recycler view) is using it in its adapter, I'll try downloading the projects and updating here

Comment: Hmm, Hits [only uses `JsonUtils.getStringFromJSONPath`](https://git.io/vpT0T) which itself just [calls `JsonPath.read`](https://git.io/vpT0O). Because we don't need to expose `Predicate` in any way, the dependency is defined as `implementation`. This should let you use InstantSearch Android as long as you don't reference explicitly `Predicate`. Let me know if you have the same issue with the example apps!

Comment: this is the error          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Lcom/jayway/jsonpath/Predicate;
at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getObjectFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:40)
 at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.JSONUtils.getStringFromJSONPath(JSONUtils.java:22)
at com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:473)
atcom.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits$HitsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Hits.java:409)

Comment: import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException;

Comment: i havet been able to build the examples @PLNech

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It seems there is a problem in the way the library was published, which results in gradle not resolving the library correctly. I'm investigating and will keep you updated

Comment: @martinseal1987 version 1.7.24 should resolve the issue, as you can see in the [latest example apps](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples/tree/140b611e4cbec47b45bb45d7012ca7541f90f843).

Comment: thank you very much have tested this and it is indeed fixed

Comment: Glad to hear! I updated the answer with the right version, feel free to accept it to mark your question as resolved :)